# Debug .NET HttpWebRequest

Tags: .net, debugging, httpwebrequest, packet-sniffers

Visual Studio 2010 .NET 3.5

Is there any tool that can trace the http request/response that send between my web application to the remote server? I use Wireshark or Fiddler, but both seem not so fit. Please advise, thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with Wireshark? In general, what "seems not to fit"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or (in FireFox): [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/) and [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/). FWIW: I recently used Tamper Data and Live HTTP Headers on HTTPS, so I know from experience that they're both very capable for this. I seem to remember previously using Charles, Fiddler, and Wire Shark for this as well.

I'm a big fan of Fiddler and Wire Shark also, but you already said these aren't working for you. They've yet to fail me, but I don't know the particulars of your situation so I'll assume these aren't conducive for your scenario. There is a learning curve on these so they may be worth revisiting. IMHO they (and Charles) are some of the best tools out there and worth the bit of time to beat the learning curve.

*Edit* As per Richard's recommendation in the comments: FireBug is also popular. I've never personally used this but it has a good reputation.

Comment: you should include FireBug in this list, its networking tab includes a log of all requests with heads/content and timing information.

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to see an HTTP request that Fiddler can't trap and dissect.  HTTPS can be a bit tricky, but HTTP is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Fiddler has a hard time trapping HTTP requests to the ASP.NET debug server. I use http://www.pocketsoap.com/tcptrace/ for that.